# Transfer Multiple objects from Salesforce to S3 using Appflow

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-appflow

I have around 70 objects that need to be transferred from Salesforce to S3 using Appflow. I have created the flow but it is letting me select only one object at a time. I want to ask if there is a way with which I can transfer all 70 objects together from Salesforce to S3. Or will I have to create a separate flow for each object i.e. 70 flows in Appflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mayank, Currently you have to create separate Appflow's for each Object. May be in the future if Appflow allows to send multiple objects.